# A DNS record for both www and non-www websites

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record

For each website I have, I noticed that having *just* this A DNS record:

```
*.example.com   3600    A   0   192.1.2.3
```

will make http://example.com unavailable and having *just* this A DNS record:

```
example.com 3600    A   0   192.1.2.3
```

will make http://www.example.com unavailable.

**Question: is it mandatory to have two A DNS records to support www and non-www**

```
*.example.com   3600    A   0   192.1.2.3
example.com     3600    A   0   192.1.2.3
```

**or is there a way to define both in one A DNS record?**

---

PS: If it's mandatory to have two records, would you use:

```
www.example.com 3600    A   0   192.1.2.3
example.com     3600    A   0   192.1.2.3
```

or would you do it this way:

```
www.example.com 3600    CNAME example.com
example.com     3600    A   0   192.1.2.3
```

?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes.

**Longer:** I would suggest you adding exactly `www.example.com` and not `*.example.com` unless you don't want to ever use any sub-domain like `john.example.com` and `jane.example.com`, etc....

Also, do not forget to configure your apache/nginx (which ever you use) to accept connections for both domain names.

Comment: Thank you @Bert fo your answer. I added a small PS at the end of the question, would you use one `A` and one `CNAME`, or two `A` records to handle both www and non-www?

Comment: Two `A` records, I would.

Comment: @Bert any particular reason for that choice?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the second part of your question:
For names I *know* will be served by the same machine for the foreseeable future I personally prefer defining one A record and then using CNAMEs as aliases for that record. That way I can change an address in one place and have everything move with it.

A typical example:
A load balancer/reverse proxy might get an A record with the name `lbtest.example.com` to point at its IP address.

Each name served by that specific machine (`example.com`, `www.example.com`, `foo.example.com`) would get a CNAME pointing at `lbtest.example.com`.